# How to truncate x bytes from file

Tags: objective-c, file, byte

Quite simply, how do I remove x amount of bytes, or a string from (the end of) a file..? I know how to append bytes — I need to do the opposite.

Unfortunately I haven't found any examples of how to do this :-/

```
NSFileHandle* fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: path];
    [fh seekToEndOfFile];

    ??
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`NSFileHandle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a [`truncateFileAtOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/truncateFileAtOffset%3a) method that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Given the NSString sFilePath variable is set, this is how you could truncate the file to 0 bytes:

```c
NSFileHandle *hFile;
hFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:sFilePath];
[hFile truncateFileAtOffset: 0];
[hFile closeFile];
```